# Send huge(possibly) packets through python basic sockets and C#

Tags: c#, python, sockets

I've created this code that links a C# client to a Python server. It does not seem to work correctly. I'm using only basic python sockets and C# sockets.
The problem is that mainly, when I send small sockets(that their size is lower than 2048), they're sent prefectly fine. But when I try to send more, it just corrupts it.

networking.py:

```
 import socket
    def send(obj, sock):
        st = obj.__repr__()
        while len(st) >= 2048:
            sock.send(st[:2047])
            st=st[:2048]
        st += "\0" * (2048 - len(st))
        sock.send(st)

    def recv(sock):
        rec = sock.recv(2048)
        while rec[len(rec)-1] != "\0":
            rec+= sock.recv(2048)
        rec=rec.replace('\0', "")
        return rec
```

Networking.cs:

```
    private void Send(string st)
    {
        int a = 0;
        while (st.Length >= 2048)
        {
            string ready = st.Substring(0, 2048);
            a += ready.Length;
            buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ready);
            connection.Send(buffer);
            st = st.Substring(2048);
        }
        a += st.Length;
        while (st.Length < 2048)
            st += "\0";
        buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(st);
        connection.Send(buffer);
    }
    private string Recv()
    {
        Array.Clear(buffer, 0, 2048);
        connection.Receive(buffer);
        string rec = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);

        while (!rec.EndsWith("\0"))
        {
            Array.Clear(buffer, 0, 2048);
            connection.Receive(buffer);
            rec += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
        }
        rec = rec.Replace("\0", "");
        return rec;
    }
```

Comment: `st=st[:2048]` Shouldn't it be `st=st[2048:]`?

Comment: But you are explicitly receiving a max of 2048 here: rec = sock.recv(2048)